# Customising iphone cameraview(overlay)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, camera, uiimagepickercontroller

My iPhone app allows the user to record videos.
How can I customize my camera view like in the screen shots.(also I need to make a custom timer-countDown)

[image]
[image]

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: I have tried this...http://www.devsrealm.com/objective-c/custom-camera-app-3/

Comment: An the problem is? The more time you invest inmaking your question more clear, the more chance you have that it will get some attention, and eventually, a decent reply.

Answer (score 0):

You need to put all the custom elements in a `UIView` and assign that view to the `cameraOverlayView` property.

```
- (void)takePicture {
    if (([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:
          UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera] == NO)) return;

    UIImagePickerController *imagePickerController = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    imagePickerController.delegate = self;
    imagePickerController.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
    // add a custom view overlay
    [imagePickerController setCameraOverlayView:customView];

    [self presentModalViewController:imagePickerController animated:YES];
    [imagePickerController release];
}
```

See also http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIImagePickerController_Class/UIImagePickerController/UIImagePickerController.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIImagePickerController/cameraOverlayView